# How to find subgroups statistics in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am grouping a DataFrame using multiple columns (e.g., columns A, B -> `my_df.groupby(['A','B'])` ), is there a better (less lines of code, faster) way of finding how many rows are in each subgroup and how many subgroups are there in total? at the moment I am using:

```
def get_grp_size(grp):
    grp['size'] = len(grp)
    return grp
my_df = my_df.groupby(['A','B']).apply(get_grp_size)
my_df[['A','B','size']].drop_duplicates().size
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_df.groupby(['A', 'B']).count()
len(my_df.groupby(['A', 'B']).groups)
```

to add column with counts you can use [transform](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html#transformation):

```
df["size"] = df.groupby(['A', 'B']).transform(len)
```

Comment: Thanks! The result is a dataframe with the count replacing all columns (except 'A' and 'B') values. Is there a way to get it in a new column?

Comment: so you want count column in your original dataFrame? like count(*) over(partition by A, B) in SQL?

Comment: I don't know the SQL equivalent but yes the result you have described is the one I am after.